# JSP getting object from backend and manipulating in JS

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jspx

I'm trying to get an array of objects in JSP, the problem is I need to manipulate the object I get later in JS, so I'm doing:

```
<c:forEach items="${ids}" var="idsP">
    <script>
        var object = ${idsP};
        console.log(object);      
    </script>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem with this code is that I get the reference to the instance of the object, so I'm getting in the console output:

`co.com.processonline.entities.documentManagement.DocumentalTypeInstance@5dedbbe`

If I try to get each attribute individually it works fine, but I need to get all the attributes in the object, Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: if you override equals method in your class then I guess you wont get values like @5dedbbe

Comment: @SpringLearner Can you be a little more specific? I can overwrite it, but how should it be overwritten?

Comment: IDE like eclipse and intellij have a option to override equals method. In intellij right click->generate->override equals and hashcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse to json before print in your JSP

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I do:
  var a = ${ids};
  console.log(JSON.parse(a));
I get a sintax error

Comment: the content of ${ids} is a JSON string or object?

Comment: Is a Java object, In my controller I'm doing 
model.addAttribute("ids", documentalType.getDocumentalTypeInstances());

Comment: using Gson lib you could do something like this model.addAttribute("ids", new Gson().toJson(documentalType.getDocumentalTypeInstances()))